# Expo 49 does not work with victory-native

Tags: react-native, expo, victory-charts

After following [the official docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native/) documentation to install `victory-native` in my Expo project, I'm encountering an issue. None of the components mentioned in the documentation can be imported. What should I do to fix this?

**Expo SDK is 49**

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade victory-native to 36.3.1 worked for me:

- `yarn add victory-native@36.3.1`
- `yarn add react-native-svg@13.14.0`

Comment: the instructions on the victory-native website appear to be out of date / incorrect. they have switched to using @shopify/react-native-skia: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native-xl#installation. their new docs: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory-native/